# Apache not logging errors in error log. It is just displaying the same few lines

Tags: python, apache, ubuntu-16.04

Following is the thing getting displayed as I try to access by Apache error log (in my digital ocean server):

```
[Tue Aug 29 06:25:02.680766 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 8282:tid 
140418378721152] AH01909: mydomainname.com:443:0 server certificate 
does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Aug 29 06:25:02.681138 2017] [wsgi:warn] [pid 8282:tid 
140418378721152] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.5.1+.
[Tue Aug 29 06:25:02.681148 2017] [wsgi:warn] [pid 8282:tid 
140418378721152] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.5.2.
[Tue Aug 29 06:25:02.683899 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 8282:tid 
140418378721152] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.2g m 
od_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/3.5.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Aug 29 06:25:02.683936 2017] [core:notice] [pid 8282:tid 
140418378721152] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Aug 30 06:25:01.905011 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 8282:tid 
140418378721152] AH00493: SIGUSR1 received.  Doing graceful restart
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully 
qualified domain name, using fe80::705e:5bff:fe93:1faf. Set the 
'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

Errors are not getting displayed. Kindly suggest.

P.S.: I've suppressed my original domain name with mydomainname.com

As requested by Mr. Dumpleton, here is my apache settings:

```
Alias /xxxxxxx /home/user_name/project/static/static_distributor
<Directory /home/user_name/project/static/static_distributor>
    Require all granted
</Directory>



WSGIDaemonProcess distributor_nossl python-home=/home/user_name/name_of_virtualenv_folder python-path=/home/user_name/project/django_project_folder
WSGIProcessGroup distributor_nossl
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user_name/project/django_project_folder/django_project_subfolder/wsgi.py process-group=distributor_nossl
<Directory /home/user_name/project/django_project_folder/django_project_subfolder>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

SSLCertificateFile 
/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mydomainname.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile 
/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mydomainname.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
ServerName mydomainname.com
ServerAlias www.mydomainname.com
```

I am using letsencrypt for SSL.

Comment: What do you mean, "not logging errors"?  Those look like errors to me (especially the first line).

Comment: Exactly. The first line is seemingly an error (The letsnecrypt SSL issue I'm failing to understand). But one of the user saw a 403 error (about 10 mins back) and this error did not get logged. Moreover, this issue is happening the 3rd/4th time.

Comment: 403 means the user did something wrong, not that Apache encountered a problem.  I'm not sure that 403s are logged in the error log normally.

Comment: Ohh is it? 403 is not logged in apache? Thanks a lot. I would like to know 2 things then, 1: How to solve the SSL error issue & 2. ANy suggestions where 403 errors would be logged?

Comment: Are all requests returning 403, or just some? Either way, this is going to be due to how you have configured Apache and since you don't provide any configuration it is impossible to guess.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton.... Thanks for your reply.... Well, some of the requests are sometimes returning 403....but, as soon as the page is refreshed, it's again working. I fail to understand what's the issue.

Comment: You need to determine if the 403 is coming from your web application or Apache. Try and determine from the content of the 403 page what is returning it.

Comment: I shall check it out. Actually, I have never faced the 403 error. A couple of my clients saw it. I shall ask them to take screenshots and then shall try to solve it. Point is, there's no log for this 403 error. I shall try to check it out. Regarding the "server certificate 
does NOT include an ID which matches the server name" , can I request some help?